# Synonym [accident] to [failure]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I ran across [accident](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident) today. It has 23 questions and no excerpt or wiki. But we already have [failure](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failure) (87 questions, 1 overlap), which is already the synonym for [launch-failure], [failed-mission] and [mistakes]. [accident](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accident) seems like it would fit better as a synonym there.

Comment: We don't have an explosion tag, so I've used failure instead.  Would that be a useful synonym as well?

Comment: I would open a separate topic and ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed and merged.